# How to improve DensityPlot resolution?

Tags: plotting

```
DensityPlot[
 Cos[φ] Cos[ArcSin[((1 + y) Sin[φ])/(-2 + y)]]/
  Cos[(φ + ArcSin[((1 + y) Sin[φ])/(-2 + y)])/
   2], {φ, -π/2, π/2}, {y, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

around the point (0,2) value of the plotted function must be 1, but the density plot shows white space at this point. How can we improve that?

we can check the plotted function along y and for $\phi=0$ as follows

```
Block[{φ = 0}, 
 Plot[Cos[φ] Cos[ArcSin[((1 + y) Sin[φ])/(-2 + y)]]/
   Cos[(φ + ArcSin[((1 + y) Sin[φ])/(-2 + y)])/2], {y, 0, 
   3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: But  `y` actually not equal to `2`.

Comment: I modified the question. it is around the point y=2

Comment: Maybe is not **1**. Try `Limit[Cos[\[CurlyPhi]] Sec[
   1/2 (\[CurlyPhi] + 
      ArcSin[((1 + y) Sin[\[CurlyPhi]])/(-2 + y)])] Sqrt[
  1 - ((1 + y)^2 Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]^2)/(-2 + 
     y)^2], {y, \[CurlyPhi]} -> {2, 0}]` ?

Comment: this give me 1, `Block[{\[CurlyPhi] = 0}, 
 Limit[Cos[\[CurlyPhi]] Sec[
    1/2 (\[CurlyPhi] + 
       ArcSin[((1 + y) Sin[\[CurlyPhi]])/(-2 + y)])] Sqrt[
    1 - ((1 + y)^2 Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]^2)/(-2 + y)^2], y -> 2]]`

Comment: Although the iterated limitation `Limit[Limit[f[φ, y], φ -> 0], y -> 2]
` equal to `1`, but since `f[φ, y]` does not define on `y=2`, so the function `f[φ, x]` is discontinuous at point `{φ, y}={0,2}`. It means that the result `DensityPlot` of Mathematica is right.

Comment: but the white space is large not only at one point? I tried `Exclusions->y==2` bit did not help